# Find lines matching a pattern, provided their value in a specified column occurs exactly twice in the input file

Tags: unix, awk, grep

Say the input is (.csv file):

```
a,b_b,3,c
d,k_k,3,f
g,h_h,3,i
j,k_k,4,l
m,n_n,4,o
p,k_k,5,q
r,s_s,5,t
```

I want this output:

All lines containing the pattern "k_k" whose number in the third column is found in exactly two lines (ex.: numbers 4 and 5):

```
j,k_k,4,l
p,k_k,5,q
```

It might be a simple one but I can't find I way to achieve this. Could anyone help me using Unix command lines (awk)?

```
awk '/k_k/' && ?? file.csv
```

Comment: There is no line `j,k_k,4,l` in your input, nor is there `p,k_k,5,9`. Please fix and/or clarify. It's also very unclear what `and that the number in the third column is find in only two lines` means.

Comment: Does "In only two lines" mean (a) in *exactly* 2 lines, or (b) in *at most* 2 lines? The question title suggests the latter; please clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$3]++;next} /k_k/ {if(a[$3]==2)print $0}' file file
```

I am assuming you mean that the number in column 3 appears exactly twice in the file, not that it is the number 4 or 5. This solution makes 2 passes over your file to count the number of times each number occurs in column 3 the first time and to print matching lines the second time. Therefore the input file is specified twice on the command line.

As a note of explanation, it counts the number of times 1 occurs in column 3 in a[1], and it counts the number of times 2 occurs in column 3 in a[2] etc...

Reading your question title, it says "2 lines maximum", so if occurring in one single line is also ok, you should change the "==" in my code to "<=". I cannot tell what you mean.

Comment: +1. FWIW I'd have used an equality test on field 2, put the test on the a[$3] in the condition section and dropped the redundant print $0: `awk -F, 'NR==FNR{cnt[$3]++; next} ($2=="k_k") && (cnt[$3]==2)' file file` but otherwise same approach.